# Keeping users logged in when session quit with cookies and Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I would like to be able to keep users logged in to their account on a Wordpress site, even if they close the browser and end session. Is there a simple way to do this with persistent cookies and Wordpress?

Thanks

Comment: Tell them to tick the "remember me" box on the login form...? Or do you want to completely remove the possibility of logging out?

Comment: I just want to keep them logged in once they've logged in, and only log them out when they choose to log out. This is without a "remember me" box

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a plugin for this very thing! Recently updated also.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-persistent-login/

You can of course have a look at the code to see how it's done. But it essentially uses a mixture of cookies and a custom DB table to keep track of users, creating unique ID's each time they login to ensure only that user is logging in.