# Woocommerce keep guest shopping cart after login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I tried these steps.

1. Login as member on woocommerce website
2. Add 3 products to member shopping cart
3. Logout (see that cart is now empty)
4. Add 1 different product to guest shopping cart
5. Go to checkout page, login on the checkout page
6. After login, can see the cart items changed from the 1 product to the original 3 products i added in step 2

After login, my ideal system behavior is I want my items in guest shopping cart in step 4, to replace the member shopping cart in step 2.

How can I do that?

Using woocommerce v7.6.0, and wordpress v6.2

Comment: What is the use case for this? If a user is logged in, has items in their cart, then logs out, puts more stuff in their cart, logs back in - wouldn't it make more sense to combine the cart contents? You may want to look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873175/keeping-users-logged-in-when-session-quit-with-cookies-and-wordpress

Comment: Thks for the recommendation. Yes, making them stay logged in is one way to solve it, but right now we just migrated from old to new website and all users are logged out by default. We have customer complaints saying they added items to cart and after login these items disappeared.

Comment: Ah! You could probably clear **all** customer sessions. Go to Woocommerce > Status > Tools. Look for the "Clear customer sessions" section and clear them out. You could probably do the "clear transients" button as well. I'm under the assumption that you migrated the database to the new site. If so, customer sessions may come with it. Something to try.